# How to prevent duplicate server calls on game logic (multiplayer)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, impactjs

So I have a game that runs on runs on html5 canvas using a game engine (ImpactJS to be exact, yeah too old)

And I have this scenario where:

After a set time (i.e. 15 seconds), game will communicate to the server.

IF:

Player A made the call, player B should not be able to make another one. Vice versa.

What I tried to do is to set a flag whenever a player makes the call to try and prevent the other player to make a new one, but I am having a problem if both players make the call **at the same time**

Is my only option is to make the timing come from the server, not the client (players)?

Do note also that the engine's update function runs 60/s or depending on the fps capability of the device.

Comment: One server to host them all, be it a server, or client hosting (as server) the game, one central control, else you create a peer-to-peer network which for most realtime games is far from ideal